# What Should I Do If My Model Is Not Immediately Intuitive?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

I was fitting a 2nd-degree polynomial on my data and found a simple relationship between $h$ and $k$:
$$y \ \ = \ \ ax^2 + bx + c \ \ = \ \ a(x - h)^2 + k$$
This is very appealing mathematically but not immediately intuitive.  In a situation like this, what can I do to further investigate whether the model is informative?  I know there is no definitive answer, but if you ran into a similar experience before, please share some insights.

**Edit:**

I am working on a set of insurance loss data to figure out how the cumulative loss grows over time.  Usually, it grows very quickly in the beginning and then flattens out.  I chose the 2-nd degree polynomial (one that opens down) because the $R^2$ is high.  Then, I rewrote the equation into the one with $h$ and $k$ for its geometric interpretation.  So, imagine that the $x$-axis is time while the $y$-axis is cumulative loss.  The apex $(h, k)$ is an estimate of when the cumulative loss hits its maximum and how much it will be.  It is known that as $h$ increases, $k$ increases as well.  I just didn't expect a specific $k = f(h)$ and didn't know how to find a theoretical justification.

Comment: All you showed is a "complete the square" operation, very standard school algebra. We need more specific information on what you're actually asking about.

Comment: If you can write $h$ as a function of $k$, or the other way around, you have a two parameter model instead of a three parameter model.  That is much more impressive.  If you can find a theoretical justification of the relationship, so much the better.  Maybe that is what your data are trying to tell you.

Comment: The model with parameters $a,h,k$ seems very informative to me. $h$ gives you the left-right center, $k$ it will be the $y$ coordinate of the center (the vertex of the parabola), and the $a$ parameter tells you how "steep" is the parabola (also if it's upside down)